# How to do localized routes in sapper

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I am converting a *svelte* website to a *sapper* website. The current routing library had the ability to specify aliases for routes, so in my localized case, mydomain.com/hello-world and mydomain.com/vamos-companeros would be the same route/component, only the language on the page would change. I read this in the [docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Routing):

> If you want to capture more params, you can create nested folders using the same naming convention: [slug]/[language].

but that unfortunately does not fit my use case. Anybody an idea whether and how this is accomplishable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it now was to create a common component *_component.svelte* which would not get used as a route and move all my shared logic there. The components *hello-world.svelte* and *vamos-companeros.svelte* would reset title and meta tags and then pass the text for the page to *_component.svelte*, which renders them together with other shared assets like images.